# How to make Array.reduce work with TypeScript tuple

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples

My code sample below is a reducer that rounds each number in a given array.

```js
type Values = [number, number];

export function roundValues(input: Values): Values {
  return input.reduce((all, current) => [...all, current], []);
}
```

However, it gives the error `TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Values'`. Any idea how I can make this reducer work with the appropriate types?

Before switching to a tuple type, my previous code looked like the code sample below. I'm not sure if it's implemented correctly as I'm new to TypeScript, but it never gave me any errors. I expected the types `number[]` and `[number, number]` to be fundamentally identical (except for  their possible length) and not cause any issues here.

```js
type Values = number[];

export function roundValues(input: Values): Values {
  return input.reduce<Values>((all, current) => [...all, current], []);
}
```

Comment: The problem is that it's hard to type this implicitly. Are you *sure* you want to do this via `.reduce`? Because it sounds like you just want to do an operation on each value so `.map` is the idiomatic choice *and* it should handle the types correctly without needing anyting.

Comment: Your code does not comply with the rules of a Tuple: `Type '[number, number, number]' is not assignable to type 'Values'. Source has 3 element(s) but target allows only 2`. And you are better off using a `map` as suggested by VLAZ.

Comment: @VLAZ @entiendoNull Yes you're right, it should be a `map`. It used to remove entries, but not anymore. However, I'm still running into the same issue, and can't get the `Array.map` to work with the tuple and get the exact same error message. Could you please provide me with a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `map` function instead of `reduce` like you mentioned in the comments.

`map` is always returning an array of unspecific size.
You have to cast the return value to the tuple again. Because its a map function I assume this is a save typecast.

```js
type Values = [number, number];
export function roundValues(input: Values) {
  return input.map((value) => Math.round(value)) as Values;
}
```